# jdbcTemplate batchUpdate can't capture the exception and rollback all rows

Tags: postgresql, jdbctemplate

I use pgsql as the db server.
Below is the library info
postgresql-42.2.14.jar
spring-boot-starter-jdbc 2.3.2 Release
The problem is when I use jdbcTemplate batchUpdate to insert a serise of data, when one of the query failed then all the succeeded one would be **rollback automatically** which I don't expect
I have set the reWriteBatchedInserts to true to split all the insert query.
When I tried to switch to use mysql this issue doesn't happen, the succeeded rows will not be rollback.
Hope for the solution or any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That is default behavior. You can annotate transaction with  `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` or check out noRollbackFor property for fine-grained approach

Comment: That action *-*is exactly** what you want. It is basically the concept of ***Atomicity**: A transaction is a complete unit. It either succeeds as a whole or fails as a whole*. It is one of the pillars of any database (well at least a relational database). You should search `ATOMIC transactions`. If that does not happen is mysql then that is a failure of mysql.